# Problem in Linear search to solve a twoSum problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the easiest problem in Leecodes to solve a twoSum,

The problems:

> Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>   You may assume that each input would have **exactly** one solution, and you may not use the *same* element twice.

My Conceptual  Plan:  Fix the first number and find (target - first)
Used:  an O(n) iteration * O(n) linear search

```
from typing import List 
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):  #loop 
            find = target - nums[i]
            print(i, find)
            for j in range(i, len(nums)):#linear search 
                if find == nums[j]:
                    print(j)
                    return [i, j]
        return None
```

When tried to check it

```
In [51]: Solution().twoSum(nums, target)                                                                                      
0 3
0
Out[51]: [0, 0]
```

Failed to find the problems and depressed to be stuck with the easiest problem in leecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping from `i + 1` to `len(nums)` in the second loop as you cannot use the same element twice. Other than that it looks correct.